# How to correct the decimal fractions?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
void toBase (int n, int base)
{
    string x = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    if (n > 0)
    {
      toBase(n / base, base);
        cout << x[n % base];
    }
}

int main()
{

    float num;
    int a;
    cout << "";
    cin >> num;
    cout << "";
    cin >> a;
    toBase(num, a);
    cout << ".";
    float fNum = 12.34;
    int iPart = (int)fNum;
    float fPart = fNum - (float)iPart;
    toBase(fNum, a);
    cout << endl;


    }
```

I posted a similar question before, and here i am again. I just can't get the decimal fractions to work. I tried multyplying by 2, but it didn't work, i'm not very good at this so i'm hoping for some help. Anyways, i'm supposed to create a code that converts decimal numbers (with decimal fractions) into other bases (from 2 to 16) - So far, only 2 of the 10 test results are correct.

```
10.5 - 1010.1 - 1010.1100   
2      
3.827 - 10.2110222122 - 10.110   
3     
82.7593 - 101.6744681322 - 101.13    
9     
7218.8192 - 5472.90139A8535 - 5472.11    
11     
8273.8 - 26B8.C - 26B8.C    
15     
23517.75 - 5BDD.C - 5BDD.C
16    
92.33271 - 1011100.0101010100 - 1011100.1100
2     
4095.839 - 7777.6554426416 - 7777.14    
8     
29672.9311 - 13033220.3232113021 - 13033220.30    
4     
9999.987 - 270F.FCAC083126 - 270F.C    
16
```

As you can see, the numbers before the dot are always correct, but the decimal fractions (except in two cases) are always wrong. (10.5 and 2 are the decimal numbers and the base, the second number is what i should get, the third number is what i get).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to treat the integral part and the fractional part separately. Loosely speaking, you must move away from the decimal point for both parts, or move the digits towards the decimal point. So while for the integral part you divide by `base` to move the more significant digits towards the decimal point, for the fractional part you have to multiply by `base` to move the less significant digits towards the decimal. Roughly,

```
while (not_enough_digits) {
    fractional_part *= base;
    int digit = (int)fractional_part;
    fractional_part -= digit;
    std::cout << x[digit];
}
```

Of course, unless `base` is a power of 2, you may get rounding errors, so only so many digits are correct, and the fractional part will never become zero (unless due to rounding) for odd bases, so the loop condition cannot be `fractional_part != 0`.

Example, 3.827 in base 3, the fractional part

```
3*0.827 = 2.481 ~> digit 2
3*0.481 = 1.443 ~> digit 1
3*0.443 = 1.329 ~> digit 1
3*0.329 = 0.987 ~> digit 0
3*0.987 = 2.961 ~> digit 2
3*0.961 = 2.883 ~> digit 2
...

10.211022...
```

Comment: Interestingly, there can be only a limited number of rounding errors and only in initial digits. Once you multiply and subtract a digit, the subtraction is exact and leaves a few bits free in the significand for the next multiplication to be exact, if it does not produce a digit that crosses another power-of-two boundary. Once you have reached the highest power of two possible in the given base, there will be no more rounding errors. So they will not accumulate. This means it is the earlier digits that may be incorrect; the later ones are correct given what has come before!

Comment: Would it be easier if i just tried to add an equation that gets the remainder and then just send it toBase instead of a fixed number as mentionied in Mark's comment, or is that just not possible in this case?

Comment: @blackbriar I'm afraid I don't understand your question. You already split the number into the integral and fractional part in `main`. You could do that in `toBase`, then handle the integral part as you do now, then `std::cout << '.';`, then handle the fractional part, stopping when `fractional_part == 0` or you have enough digits (add a counter).

Comment: @blackbriar: No, that will not work. As currently written, `toBase` converts an integer to just as many digits as needed to represent it. It never produces leading zeroes. But some fractions must have leading zeroes, such as .0047. So, even if you extracted the fraction part and multiplied it to produce an integer, `toBase` would never convert this integer to “0047”. If you modified `toBase` to produce leading zeroes upon request, you could get some fractions. But then you need to consider suppressing trailing zeroes and deciding how many digits to produce.

Answer (score 1):

You're using a fixed number for `fNum` instead of getting the remainder. Notice that in every case the decimal part is the equivalent of `12`.

Since decimal numbers can't usually be represented exactly in binary floating point, you'll need to decide how many decimal digits you're interested in and do some rounding.

Comment: The assignment says that the number should have 10 decimal fractions maximum.

Comment: I don't know if rounding is necessary (it probably is), the rounding inherent to floating point _might_ prevent infinite digits.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Infinite digits are possible. Proof: Convert .5 to base 3. The conversion will multiply by 3, producing 1.5. The 1 becomes a digit in the numeral, and the .5 is a remainder that continues in the algorithm. Then .5 is multiplied by 3 to get the next digit. The result is “.11111…”, continuing without end.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: alright, I figured that was the case, but I wasn't certain